# Start Section page different style

Tags: sectioning

I'm using the `fancyhdr` package for writing a document and I'd like each section of the document to start at half page (even better if I could decide height), and the section's name and number to be flushed on the right part of the page.

Furthermore, in the starting page of a section I'd like to remove the header, and have the number of the page on the bottom and not in the top.

What a new section is like in my case:

[image]

what I'd like it to be (don't mind the style, just the position of title and section number):

[image]

should I use a certain package or are there some commands I should use at the beginning of each section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use a document class with `\chapter` sectional units; in the standard classes, the first page of a chapter has `plain` page style (no header and page number on the bottom, as required). To customize the formatting for the chapter headings you can use, for example, the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package. A little example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}
  {#1\hfill\rlap{\makebox[2em][r]{\Huge\thechapter}}}[\vskip15pt\titlerule]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{60pt}{20pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Example}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thks for pointing out a solution, it was very helpful! :) can I just ask you please to explain me with some comments what are the commands you used?thks in advance!